# EF Core eager loading is returning null for related object

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to eager load in related data `DrinkCategory`. However, it is not working and I can't figure out why DrinkCategory is still null.

This is my `Drink` model:

```
public class Drink
{
    [Key]
    public int DrinkId { get; set; }

    public int DrinkCategoryId { get; set; }
    public DrinkCategory DrinkCategory{ get; set; }
}
```

This is my `DrinkCategory` model:

```
public class MenuItemViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int DrinkCategoryId { get; set; }

    public List<Drink> Drinks{ get; set; }
}
```

I eager load it like this:

```
_Context.Drinks.Include(item=> item.DrinkCategory);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `.ToList` in your query. Write your query as follows:

```
_Context.Drinks.Include(item=> item.DrinkCategory).ToList();
```

Comment: Right, this makes sense, It works great now thanks.